# How to change ComboBox's Background Property during Mouse Hover

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a Rounded Border containing a ComboBox as follow:

[image]

As soon as my mouse hover on the ComboBox, I get this

[image]

I want to get rid of the button-like background. I tried setting background to white or null in **MouseEnter**, **MouseLeave**, **MouseUp**... everything with Mouse but still I can't get rid of the default button background on the ComboBox. Does anyone has a clue?

Code below:

```
/* XAML */
<Border CornerRadius="11" BorderThickness="1" Height="24" Width="70" 
    Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White">
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
          Background="{x:Null}" Width="70" MouseMove="MouseHover"
          MouseEnter="MouseHover"
    </ComboBox>
    </Border>

/* C# code */
private void MouseHover(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Background = null;
}
```

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar Hiremath, question is edited with code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to style WPF ComboBox on Mouse Hover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563536/unable-to-style-wpf-combobox-on-mouse-hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the [default controlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of the Combobox for this.Check the link below

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/a18891e9-8879-4819-9679-247341782f60

Answer (score 1):

The background is set by a style trigger in the default `ComboBox` style, which activates when `IsMouseOver` is `true`.

There are a couple of ways around this: either override the trigger in your own style, or set `BasedOn="{x:Null}"` in your own ComboBox style to prevent the base style from being inherited.

Comment: I cannot find "BasedOn" as an attribute of ComboBox.

Comment: `BasedOn` is an attribute of a `Style`.  How are you styling your ComboBox at the moment?  You should maybe post some of your xaml.

Comment: Actually, I may be wrong - I think the part of the style that handles the mouseover is embedded deeper in the style somewhere.  Probably not so simple!