# How to style ComboBox Background on Mouse Hover?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a Rounded Border that contains a ComboBox

```
<Border CornerRadius="10"  BorderBrush...>
   <ComboBox Background="{x:Null}">
      <ComboBoxItem ...>
      <ComboBoxItem ...>
   </ComboBox>
</Border>
```

When my mouse is not hovering on top of the Combobox, it looks nice and transparent. Like this:

[image]

When the mouse hovers on it, it then produce the old, Button-like, background, like this:

[image]

I would like the ComboBox to have with a transparent background even when mouse is hoving on top. I tried various ways including writing MouseEnter, MouseLeave, MouseMove to set the background to null, but with no success.

```
private void ComboBox_MouseEnter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   comboBox1.Background = null;
}
```

I then try to set the Styling:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="HoverBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

that didn't work either. Then I tried modifying the control template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="MouseHover">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Worst, after I modify the Control template the ComboBox disappear, like follow:

[image]

I have done everything possible, but I am still getting that ugly button-background on my ComboBox whenever my mouse is hover on it.

Anyone knows what's going wrong here?

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions

http://stackoverflow.com/q/5563536/217880,
http://stackoverflow.com/q/5562967/217880

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Previous Posts asking the same

[Unable to style WPF ComboBox on Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5563536/217880)

[How to change ComboBox's Background Property during Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5562967/217880)

**EDIT**

Use like this. Below is the default controltemplate of the combobox. Note the commented line of code for your requirement

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Fill Brushes -->

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalLightBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DarkBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#AAA" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#BBB" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#EEE" Offset="0.9"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush" Color="#888" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush" Color="#EEE" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBackgroundBrush" Color="#FFF" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="#DDD" />

        <!-- Border Brushes -->

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="NormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalNormalBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#CCC" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="DefaultedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#777" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#000" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PressedBorderBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStopCollection>
                    <GradientStop Color="#444" Offset="0.0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#888" Offset="1.0"/>
                </GradientStopCollection>
            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#888" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightBorderBrush" Color="#AAA" />

        <!-- Miscellaneous Brushes -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GlyphBrush" Color="#444" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LightColorBrush" Color="#DDD" />

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border
      x:Name="Border" 
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
      CornerRadius="2"
      Background="{StaticResource NormalBrush}"
      BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="1" />
                <Border 
      Grid.Column="0"
      CornerRadius="2,0,0,2" 
      Margin="1" 
      Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" 
      BorderBrush="{StaticResource NormalBorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" />
                <Path 
      x:Name="Arrow"
      Grid.Column="1"     
      Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
      VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <!--<Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}" />
                </Trigger>-->
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PressedBrush}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="Arrow" Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBox}" TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <ToggleButton 
            Name="ToggleButton" 
            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" 
            Grid.Column="2" 
            Focusable="false"
            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            ClickMode="Press">
                            </ToggleButton>
                            <ContentPresenter
            Name="ContentSite"
            IsHitTestVisible="False" 
            Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
            ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
            Margin="3,3,23,3"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
            Style="{x:Null}" 
            Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="3,3,23,3"
            Focusable="True" 
            Background="Transparent"
            Visibility="Hidden"
            IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"/>
                            <Popup 
            Name="Popup"
            Placement="Bottom"
            IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
            AllowsTransparency="True" 
            Focusable="False"
            PopupAnimation="Slide">
                                <Grid 
              Name="DropDown"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                    <Border 
                x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}"/>
                                    <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Grid>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
               Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility"    Value="Visible"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried to combine the answers I got and reword my question. I tried yours link already - first link: as soon as I add "Override" to the style, the whole ComboBox disappear. The second link: no - i'm sorry but it's not readable/understandable. But thanks for pointing. One vote,

Comment: according to your link, I modify the control template but still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @KMC Look at the Updated answer

Comment: Your code works! Thanks. I can't believe it takes this much code just the override the default properties.

Comment: @KMC It is because the code is embedded deep in the controltemplate of the combobox.

Comment: @biju What you say is true. It is just strange that some `Properties` are so easily editable and others are left hidden. In my experience a lot of the hidden ones are very often needed to be changed. It would be great to have a way of directly accessing hidden template elements, or editing a template without having to override it entirely.