# How to change color of border of combobox while mouse is over in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

yesterday I have written similar post concerning textbox for the same purpose. [How to set properties of textbox globally in app.xaml [C#]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36875480/how-to-set-properties-of-textbox-globally-in-app-xaml-c?noredirect=1#comment61363443_36875480) I have told also that I have problem with combobox. I have got helpful answer imiditelly which solve my problem with textbox. I was trying to apply similar solution for my combobox without success. Then I was trying to find some solution on the web including stack and msdn and other websites, without success. Then I made edit to my post from yesterday, so I was suggested to make new question, so I am doing.

So the problem which I have is that I would like to just change color of border while the mouse is over the combobox. The rest of functionality as well as design should remain for standard combobox.

I have such a code, which is working for buttons, and with modification for textboxes, but I can't apply it to comboboxes.
This code is in app.xaml in application resources.

```
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Border Name="combobox" 
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"  
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="combobox" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF0000" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF0000"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The code just I paste upper is creating a border color changing, but the content of combobox is dissappearing, actually then all functionality of combobox is dissapearing.

How I may do this last thing in my app ? May anyone told what to change this time to make it works.

Thanks in advance

p.s.
May someone recommend trusted and step by step course of xaml for beginners ? Are those techniques in xaml and wpf useful for Windows Universal Apps ?

!!!!!
edit:

You may be right, since I am not so experienced I may made a mistake in xaml.

What I have done now also the third way is:

1) add to

```
    <Style  x:Key="MyComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF0000" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF0000"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

and

2)

```
    <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource MyComboBox}" Background="#EAEAEA" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" FontSize="12" Foreground="Black" Height="49" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Loaded="ABCCombobox_Loaded" Margin="38,425,0,0" ToolTip="ABCCombobox." SelectionChanged="ABCCombobox_SelectionChanged" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="270" x:Name="ABCComboBox" />
```

What I am doing wrong ? I have found this way as suggested on the web.

Comment: Did you ever find your solution?

Comment: Hi Crhis and the others. Yesterday I have came back to this project and I have finished it. Actually, I could not use your code, there was some missing reference or other problem, Visual Studio have not recognized something. But going behind your proposal, I have tried by myself option Copy Template to app resources and there i have tried to change all properties responsible for colours for example and finally I customized combobox more or less as I wanted, just arrow have disappear, but this is no big matter. THANK YOU ! I upvoted your answer ! All of guys have a nice day !

Comment: Ya sometimes there's little nuance differences so I prefer to use templates copied straight from the project instead of from "default" documentation. Glad you got a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you were to take a look at the default `ComboBox` template (Right Click->Edit Template->Edit a copy) there's a bunch of brushes listed as resources. One of those is;

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
```

If you go a little further down, you'll see the embedded `ToggleButton` which is what `BorderBrush` is actually bound to. The first thing this tells us is `ComboBox` isn't the `TargetType` you're aiming for.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" 
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
              IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
              Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
```

Notice the `ComboBoxToggleButton` style set on there? That's the next clue. If we check out that particular style's Triggers, more specifically for `IsMouseOver` see it using that `Brush` resource we found first;

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" 
        Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
```

Ouch right? Guess it's not as simple as some hope with just hitting `BorderBrush` in the case like this when we want to alter the an actual `ControlTemplate.Triggers` `Setter`.

I hope you've been following along at this point and have already extracted the default `ComboBox` style template with the directions in the first sentence because here's your answer part.

1. You'll need to extract the template, after you do the "Edit A Copy" part choose your app.xaml or another resource dictionary and plop it in there, what you name it doesn't matter.
2. Then you'll just find the `x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border"` `SolidColorBrush` mentioned first and replace the current color with your own.
3. Since you want this to be universal now, you'll just find the `Style` of `TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}"` and simple delete the `x:Key="blah"` name you gave it when you extracted the template.

Voila, universal `IsMouseOver` change on your `ComboBox` controls. Hope this helps. This sort of thing really is much easier when it's not a scenario of an embedded control with it's own `IsMouseOver` `ControlTemplate.Triggers`

...and in case you run into troubles. Here's an example you can just throw in Whatever.Resources or your resource dictionary. Don't be intimidated by the size, it's all parts of the template. Plus when you need to make other changes in the future it will be a lot easier to just do them here;

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border" Color="#FFABADB3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FFFF0000"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF606060"/>
        <!-- // -->
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Glyph}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FFFF0000"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
       <!-- // -->
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Background="Transparent" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
                <Border x:Name="border" Background="{StaticResource TextBox.Static.Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsReadOnly, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

By replacing the Template of the ComboBox you have completely replaced all visual elements of the control. Instead of re-templating you can achieve the effect you want by adding your triggers to the style instead and leave the original template intact:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF0000" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF0000"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you want to re-template the control you can find full customisable templates on MSDN that should still support all of the standard functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer.
Unfortunatelly, this is not solving my problem. 
I have added it to app.xaml into application resources, then the combobox is disappearing at all.
In the other way if I try to put it inside <ComboBox> </ComboBox> then the following error is occuring while I try to enter window containing this combobox. 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Comment: The style in the answer is correct, it seems you don't know how to use styles. Also, remove the OverridesDefaultStyle setter.

Comment: I'm sure you just didn't take a peek at the actual template first, or test your answer first, but your answer in the case of changing `IsMouseOver` is not correct brother. So no reason to knock the OP.

Comment: His answer is correct, only problem is that he is not inheriting the default style. He just need to add "BasedOn' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think triggers will work because the `BorderBrush` that you are modifying isn't the same `BorderBrush` that is used when the mouse is over the control. I believe you have to edit the existing default style to get the feature you want.

For WPF, go to designer and right-click the ComboBox -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy.

Then change the following:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Red"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Modify the color `Value` in this line:

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
```

For Universal Apps, go to designer and right-click the ComboBox -> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy.

Then change the following:

```
<VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Modify the color `Value` in this line:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}"/>
```

Hopefully this will get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in either the XAML page where you want to use it, or in App.xaml.

```
<Style x:Key="UpdateComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" 
   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF0000" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF0000"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In the combobox, add attribute as below:

```
Style="{StaticResource UpdateComboBoxStyle}"
```

Let me know if it doesn't work. In that case, just show us the new code, so we can figure out what went wrong. Try editing the question, instead of commenting, so that others can find out the new changes.